# single QML Q_PROPERTY QString consumes high CPU (85%) emitting every 90ms

Tags: performance, qt, qml, cpu-usage

Im working on a QML app that is consuming about 85% of the CPU when I emit
a QString every 90ms to the QML display.  We are currently using Qt 5.2.  Im working on
getting us up to Qt 5.9 because at this time we cannot go past 5.9.9 due to an older
OS system.

So far the only thing I have been able to establish is that it appears because
this QString from my model is embedded down in the hierarchy of QML there is a
slowdown.  Ive also removed the ListView out of the equation of updating items there
by not emitting any changes on the backend C++ side.  Conversely if I remove
the 'emit my property()' call for the QString, CPU usage drops to 5%.

What I mean by that is that if I move the Text {} call to the top level (main.qml)
and display it, all other things being equal, my CPU usage for the app goes from
85% down to 15%.

My app uses 4 floating windows, only 1 of which is currently implemented.
My mode; property is located in the first QML 'Window' object.
I found that if I changed that (Window) to a (Rectangle) my CPU usage drops to
about 50%.

I also tried making the QString property defined at the top level (main.qml) and
just use it in the lower 'Window' component without the model specifier, essentially
using the top level one instead and found it equally slow (85%).  I have a hard time
believing that updating the screen for 1 QString causes such a CPU mess.

Unfortunately I cannot post the code because its proprietary but here is the
basic outline of what it looks like (NOT REAL CODE).

I appreciate any pointers or knowledge anyone has about this situation.  I have spent a bit of
time searching for clues online with no real solutions found yet.

Thank you!

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow
{
  Rectangle
  {
     Row
     {
        FirstWindowButton {}
        SecondWindowButton {}
        ThirdWindowButton {}
        ForthWindowButton {}
     }
  }
}
```

FirstWindowButton.qml:

```
Button
{
   Loader
   {
      sourceComponent: Window
      {
          flags: Qt.Window
          FirstWindow {}
      }
   }
}
```

FirstWindow.qml:

```
Rectangle
{
   MyListView
   {
   }
}
```

MyListView.qml:

```
Rectangle
{
   Text
   {
      text: theModel.string_value <----this is the slowdown line
   }

   ScrollView
   {
      ListView 
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Those differences are interesting and a minimal example would be useful. How long is the text btw, and how can it be readable if changing every 90 ms? (Maybe think about throttling the updates, independent of the analysis why this is slow in your setup)

Comment: Can you set a static size to that `Text { }` element and see? I suspect `Text { }` having to recalculate it's width/height triggers layout changes for the rest of the elements in MyListView and can really bring down the performance

Comment: At the moment we moved this into a main.qml until I can get more time to investigate your suggestions. I did find that making the window smaller (by dragging it smaller), especially cutting off the text from redrawing lowers the CPU dramatically.  It seems that the entire window gets redrawn for every change, so the smaller the window the less demand on the CPU.  I guess I thought Qt somehow figured out that area and only redrew those pixels, but maybe not.  Ill post back with any more results. Thanks!

Comment: I did play around with setting a Text element with fixed x,y,width,height in a view but that didn't seem to make any difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured out what was causing this issue after spending a while looking at performance issues that might cause issues with QML.  Because we were using
the `color` of a `Rectangle` to colorized the background of `ApplicationWindow` it was
having to redraw that entire `Rectangle` every 90ms.

Instead use the `color` property of `ApplicationWindow` to colorize the background.  Such a simple mistake and took many hours to figure it out.

Thank you for those who posted comments.